# Unable to control one fan with SpeedFan

Tags: fan, speedfan

In my pc, I have 4 fans: CPU, Chassis 1, 2, and 3. I can control all of the fans, except Chassis 1. However, all of the Chassis fans are identical. So my question is, why am I unable to control fan 1? So far, I have tried moving chassis fan 1 to the PWR pins to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!